# Android ndk-build failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, java-native-interface, cygwin

I'm trying to debug .so library, using NDK for Android.

I'm able to build .so library, using `ndk-build`. But when I want to debug my library,
I set `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG = 1` and receive following error: make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.

And also I receive the error: `Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?`
Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: I will start following the Cygwin suggestion. You should add an Environment variable to Cygwin

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks for reply. Can you give me the direction, how to do it, or some tutorial. I'm not familiar with Linux system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must remove the spaces in the assignment, ie

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1
```

rather than

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG = 1
```

Comment: oh, yes. I'm so inattentive. Thanks